# Too little space between wrapped text and the line below it

Tags: tables, spacing, tabu

Consider the following table example, the text in the second row is wrapped.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[.5,c] X[1,l] X[1,l] X[2,l]}
    \toprule
    \rowfont{\bfseries}
    Row & Head 1                   & Head 2 & Head 3 \\\hline
    1.  & short text               & ? & ? \\\hline
    2.  & long long long long text & ? & ? \\\hline
    3.  & short text               & ? & ? \\\hline
    4.  & short text               & ? & ? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

It renders like:

[image]

Why is there so little space between the text in the second row and the rule below it?

How can I fix it?

What comes to my mind is to use `\\[1ex]` instead of `\\`, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known deficiency of `tabu`; it adds a `\strut` at the beginning but not at the end of possibly multiline cells. Compare the outputs (I added a `g` in the short texts for better comparison).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
  \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[.5,c] X[1,l] X[1,l] X[2,l]}
    \toprule
    \rowfont{\bfseries}
    Row & Head 1                   & Head 2 & Head 3 \\\hline
    1.  & gshort text               & ? & ? \\\hline
    2.  & long long long long text & ? & ? \\\hline
    3.  & gshort text               & ? & ? \\\hline
    4.  & gshort text               & ? & ? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabu}

\bigskip

\noindent
  \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[.5,c] X[1,l]<{\strut} X[1,l] X[2,l]}
    \toprule
    \rowfont{\bfseries}
    Row & Head 1                   & Head 2 & Head 3 \\\hline
    1.  & gshort text               & ? & ? \\\hline
    2.  & long long long long text & ? & ? \\\hline
    3.  & gshort text               & ? & ? \\\hline
    4.  & gshort text               & ? & ? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]