# Tabu table with different row-spacing between one-line and multi-line rows

Tags: tables, line-spacing, tabu

during my work with Latex I encountered a problem with my tables.
As you can see in the following MWE, theses tables sometimes have rows witch contain cells with multiple lines. Those rows have less distance to the following row than a row with only one-line cells.
I have to use the tabu package because of its flexible columnwidth handling.R

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{lX[10000]}
\toprule

\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Description}
\\
\toprule
Row one & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\\
Row two & Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\\
Row three & Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.\\
Last row & One last row.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\caption{MWE}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Compiled it looks like this:

[image]

I tried several solutions, I found during my search in this community and the whole www containing one or a combination of these commands:

- `\linespread{0.5}` with `\rmfamily` or `\selectfont`
- `renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`
- `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5mm}`
- `>{\setlength{\baselineskip}{0.75\baselineskip}}` between l and X in the `\linewidth{lX[10000]}` command

Now I hope anybody can help me to solve this.

Best regards,
Gwedhwen

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136533/too-little-space-between-wrapped-text-and-the-line-below-it ?

Comment: Indeed, using `\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{lX[10000]<{\strut}}` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: @egreg thanks, this works. Is it possible to assign the `\strut` command to all columns at once? Up to now i succeed only with `\linewidth{l<{\strut}X[10000]<{\strut}}` when there are two (or more) columns which need this fix.

Comment: I think this would require changing the internals of `tabu`.

Comment: Ok, i will deal with editing `\strut`everywhere it is needed. Thanks again for your help.